# How to vectorize a function's input

Tags: python, function, vectorization

First post apologies if its a bad question, promise to improve! I'm trying to write a interpolation function for images and it's written currently with an array for a single pixel's R,G,B values. How do I expand the function to take in images with dimension shape [1080,1920,3]? I know I can write a for loop, but its a function I would be using a lot, so trying to find out if there's a faster method.

```
def tetra_interp(transform_ndarray, pixel_rgb):
  
  r = pixel_rgb[0]
  g = pixel_rgb[1]
  b = pixel_rgb[2]

  Rt = transform_ndarray[0]
  Gt = transform_ndarray[1]
  Bt = transform_ndarray[2]
  Ct = transform_ndarray[3]
  Mt = transform_ndarray[4]
  Yt =transform_ndarray[5]
  Wt =transform_ndarray[6]
  Blkt = transform_ndarray[7]

  if r>g:
    if g>b:
      interp_pixels = r*Rt + g*(Yt-Rt) + b*(Wt)
    elif r>b:
      interp_pixels = r*Rt + g*(Wt-Mt) + b*(Mt-Rt)
    else:
      interp_pixels= r*(Mt-Bt) + g*(Wt-Mt) + b*Bt
  else:
      if b>g:
        interp_pixels = r*(Wt-Ct) + g*(Ct-Bt) + b*Bt;
      elif b>r:
        interp_pixels = r*(Wt-Ct) + g*Gt + b*(Ct-Gt);
      else:
        interp_pixels = r*(Yt-Gt) + g*Gt + b*(Wt-Yt);
  return interp_pixels

rand_image = np.random.rand(10,5,3)
rand_image_reshape = rand_image.reshape(-1,3)
transform_matrix = np.array([[1.2,.2,.1],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]])
vectorized_tetra =np.vectorize(tetra_interp)
transformed_image = vectorized_tetra(transform_matrix,rand_image_reshape)
```

I'm getting an "invalid index to scalar variable" error.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts so far?

Comment: @WBM just updated the code, thank you for your time!

Comment: Note that ``numpy.vectorize`` basically *is* a for loop. From the docs: ["The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi so is there a better way other than [tetra_interp(transform_matrix,row) for row in rand_image_reshape]